# How can I track my python package's user base?

Tags: python, pypi

The PyPI used to give you the ability to track the downloads of your packages by release and month.  However, since they changed server setups this feature is no longer available.

Has anyone here come up with another way to get an idea of how your python package's user base is growing?

I know many people dislike the idea of a program "phoning-home" but is there ANY way that this can be done that is considered 'kosher'?  Can anyone suggest a less invasive way of tracking user base?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it but this looks like it may work for you. Granted it looks like just a "number of downloads" counter, so people with `virtualenvs` will get counted multiple time.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypstats/

Comment: Pretty sure that that relies on the old PyPI API that was botched by the new server setup.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the PyPI folks re-enabled the download tracking function yesterday!

example:
[Blacktie Downloads](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=blacktie&version=0.2.1qf1#downloads)